# Java override annotation value by value provided in another annotation on the same class member

Tags: java, spring, java-8

Is it possible in Java to implement annotation that will override value in another annotation on the same class member.

For example in my Spring project I have a following code which uses `org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer` annotation:

```
@ColumnTransformer(read = "read", write = "write")
private String name;
```

I need to provide "read" and "write" values from my application properties file. The main issue that `ColumnTransformer` is not a Spring annotations and don't understand Spring expression language like for example Spring Value annotation:

```
@Value("${transformer.name.read}")
```

I'm just wondering if it is possible to implement new annotation that will take a value from application properties via Spring expression language and override the values in ColumnTransformer annotation, something like this:

```
@ColumnTransformerValue(read = "${transformer.name.read}", write = "${transformer.name.write}")
@ColumnTransformer(read = "read", write = "write")
private String name;
```

Comment: Are you only looking for annotation overriding or any other alternatives to resolve the issue ?

Comment: I know how to resolve this issue with reflection. Right now I'm mostly interested in annotation based solution.

Comment: @alexanoid, We can't go without reflection here. An annotation, itself, is just a marker that provides some meta information. You have to write a class (e.g. BPP) which will process all of that

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding. When Spring allows you to specify `${transformer.name.read}`, it does not imply that the annotation value becomes the value of that property, it just implies that Spring will substitute the value during its own processing of that annotation. There is no way to let an annotation (compile-time constant value) refer to what happens in the internal processing of an arbitrary library.